# Is there a name for this construction?

Tags: formal-languages

Consider a set $S$, which we call the alphabet. What is the name for the least set $T$, such that $S$ is a subset of $T$, all finite sequences from $S$ are in $T$, all finite sequences of sequences from $S$ are in $T$, etc. For example, if we let $S$ be the natural numbers, then some of the elements of $T$ would be, $0$, $(0,1)$, $(1,(1,10),2)$, $((1,10),(2,3))$, etc. Is there a name for this construction? It is not the Kleene closure.

Comment: Are repetitions like in $(0,1,1,6,0,7,12,1)$ allowed in your sequences? The examples do not contain any.

Comment: Yes, repetitions are allowed.

Comment: "All finite sequences of sequences from $S$ are in $T$". Is this supposed to say finite sequences of finite sequences? Otherwise, one can show that you get a cardinality blowup, and conclude that if $T$ were a set, the contradiction $|T| \geq |2^{T}|$ follows.

Answer (score 0):

In formal language theory (your tag) there is no common name for this. Not even the different "layers" are treated.

- Your layer zero, the alphabet, is, of course, there.
- Your first layer, sequences of elements of the alphabet are *words* or *strings*. Note, however, that there is usually no formal distinction made between symbols and strings of length one. For you, $0$ and $(0)$ are distinct already in notation.
- The next layer sequences of sequences corresponds to (formal) *languages*. However, languages have no multiplicities and no order of their elements. While there are automata and grammars for multisets of symbols, I am not aware of devices for multisets of strings instead of languages.
- Finally, there are families/classes of languages in different contexts. But again, these are just sets, no order, no multiplicity.
- For higher layers I cannot think of any reference.

So, concluding, not even the single layers appear, let alone a mix of them all. Maybe in some different field there is something like what you are looking for. You could start by asking in general set theory.